# "BAD ARCHIVE MIRROR" error while installing ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: system-installation

- I downloaded the server version of Ubuntu from Ubuntu's official site.
- Created a Bootable USB from the ISO file I downloaded.
- I connected through Internet using DHCP in the installation process.
- While I was installing it on my Desktop Computer (pentium D 1 GB RAM) I have this error "Bad Archive Mirror".

I also found 2-3 questions with same problem on forum but I didn't get solution of my problem from them.

Comment: I solved this issue- Actually the problem was with "internet connection", i was using a net connector or e-stick (TATA PHOTON+) to connect with the internet, but when i used the broadband my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing my above comment in answer this answer.

I solved this issue- Actually the problem was with "**internet connection**",
i was using a net connector or e-stick (TATA PHOTON+) to connect with the internet, but when i used the **broadband** my problem get solved.

Thanks